# Possible ways to create a graph representation from a distance matrix (through approximation)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-distance

Forgive me, Im not math professional, but a computer scientist at the beginning of my base research from my thesis, so bare with me if I miss something blatantly obvious.

I have a Euclidean distance matrix, which represent physical distances of nodes.

My goal is to create a geometrically correct undirected graph from this data. So basically I know the edges and their lengths and I want to know the locations of the nodes relative to each other. (So it can be drawn in a simple coordinate system).

Let's say we have the following distance matrix (did not check if this is valid)

```
  | A | B | C
A | 0 | 6 | 9
B | 6 | 0 | 3
C | 9 | 3 | 0
```

My naive approach would be to pick a random node and start at `(0,0)` in a coordinate system, lets say `A`. From `A` I can draw a circle with the radius 6 and know that `B` must be somewhere on this circle. The I would draw another circle with radius 9(`A`->`C`). I pick a random point on the `B`-circle and draw a circle with radius 3. Now this circle should have two intersection on the `C` circle. Now I should have 2 possible graphs that satisfy the distance matrix. But the problem is, I read in a paper about semidefinite graphs that this kind of problem is NP, so a realistic solution would be an approximation.

There is a phyton lib that can do exactly that (approximate a graphical represenation with a distance matrix): [networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513455/drawing-a-graph-or-a-network-from-a-distance-matrix)

My question is:

Is this some kind of known problem? Are there known approximation algorithms for this or similiar problems? Is this realistically solveable in polynominal time or faster?

**Edit:** thx to the comments, I know now this topic is refered to as [distance geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry), specificially Im interessted in Sensor Network Localization. And according to the wiki article this problem is called "Sensor Network Localization problem". I found a [PhD thesis about this here](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/5093/Krislock_Nathan.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: One key term is *[distance geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry)*. Here is a survey: "[Euclidean distance geometry and applications](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0349)."

Comment: Thanks alot, that helps and gives me hope there are useful solutions to m my problem

Comment: @for3st a generic algorithm should not make assumptions about the dimension of the euclidean space. another aspect of your problem would be to check the rigidity of the graph if some distances are missing.

Comment: @ManfredWeis - for simplicity I will keep it 2D